# Gradle dependency resolution - fetch only direct dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle

I have a gradle project with the following dependencies declaration.

```
dependencies{
        implementation 'com.github.gwtmaterialdesign:gwt-material:2.1'
        implementation 'com.github.gwtmaterialdesign:gwt-material-addins:2.1'
        implementation 'com.github.gwtmaterialdesign:gwt-material-themes:2.1'
        implementation 'com.github.gwtmaterialdesign:gwt-material-table:2.1'

}
```

However, gwt-material-2.1 depends on gwt-user-2.8.2 and gwt-dev-2.8.2.
In turn they have numerous dependencies which are not required by my project.

I can disable transitive dependencies completely and manually add gwt-user and gwt-dev. However, I would like it to happen automatically but still fetch only 1st level dependencies.

Comment: Why ? Maybe your project does not need these dependencies but `gwt-material-2.1` does

Comment: For Eg: gwt-dev has compile dependencies on httpunit, jetty, etc. I do not need most of those. I have looked at nebula lint. But it doesn't work as expected.